# Stuck at loading facenet-keras model using load_models of keras.models

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying load facenet-keras model using python3, but my code stucks loading facenet model using keras with tensorflow as backend.
My code is as below:

```
from keras.models import load_model
print("Loading facenet model...")
model = load_model('models/facenet_keras_dup.h5') #code stucks at this line
print ("facenet model loaded")
```

My python version are as below:

python 3.5.2
keras 2.3.1
tensorflow 1.14

Running on Intel i3 6th Generation 3.7 Ghz CPU and Intel HD Graphics 530

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you get an error something like this:

**Value Error: Bad marshal data**

This error could be due to different version of python or keras or tensorflow.
I think we get the error because version through which facenet module  was saved could be different from our versions

**I solved it through** creating a **virtual environment** and installing the packages of the following version:

**python : 3.7.1,
Keras : 2.3.1,
Tensorflow: 2.2.0**

Note : This is a trial and error solution and the versions are the one which gave me the solution.Not the standard version required for facenet model

Answer (score 0):

**if you have pip then fist install these using the commands:

#pip install keras-facenet

#pip install tensorflow

#pip install keras-resnet

#import these libraries

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras_facenet import FaceNet
```

#import the FaceNet model

```
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
```

This should work.